# How to insert data into another table with same id by mysql or python

Tags: python, mysql

I have the following table:

[image]

I want like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: Images of code, no attempt at solving the problem, this is as bad a "question" as possible...

Answer (score -1):

I don't recommend this process because it is extremely messy, but if it helps, more power to you, I guess. Also, make sure that when you post a question, you include the code that the question is referring to. It helps other users a lot more and makes them much more willing to help!

Because MySQL will not let you put in repeat CHAR or VARCHAR columns, I suggest you either uniquely name the columns based on why they're separated this way, or make unique tables.

Unique Column Names:

```
CREATE TABLE 'tableName' (
id INT NOT NULL,
time1 TIME NOT NULL,          //Just continue naming your columns in a different way
action1 CHAR(6) NOT NULL, 
station1 VARCHAR NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(primaryKey)       //Use this to uniquely identify you table by a distinct 
);                            //variable (probably id)
```

To make unique tables, just repeat the table above over and over again with a different Table Name. To connect all your tables together, use a foreign key. This key's variable needs to have entries that exist in all tables to have all table data connected. Read more about it here: [Foreign Keys and How to Use Them](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Good Luck!

Comment: Not downvoting, but this question does not deserve an answer. It meets nearly all criteria that make it a bad question, just as bruno desthuilliers mentioned in his comment.

Comment: @shmee I realize that, but everyone deserves a little kindness when they begin on here. Pointing them in the right direction does a lot better than just saying it's a bad question and moving on. :)

Comment: Better for the OP, not the website. Rewarding people who break the rules encourages more people to do the same.

Comment: @csmckelvey 1, thanks for downvoting. 2, if you read through my whole answer, you will see that I did tell chen to write questions correctly. I am not rewarding for breaking a rule. I am trying to discourage what they are doing and giving them a reason why, which encourages them to do it properly.

Comment: For that individual: yes. For the community: not so much ;)

Comment: Anyway, thank you all, I'll make a good improvement next time